# How to create a barchart within pycharm and or fix this error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm

I wanted to creat a barchart wit python using the environment pycharm. I wrote the following code but somehow got this error. Any help is very appreciated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = df[:20,]
plt.figure(figursize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, alpha = 0.8)
plt.title ('Top Words Overall')
plt.ylabel('Words from Tweet', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Count of Words', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

I have gotten this error:

```
line 125, in <module>
    plt.figure(figursize=(10,5))
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no property 'figursize'
```

and this one:

```
line 126, in <module>
    sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, alpha = 0.8)
NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex
```

If anyone has other solutions on how to create a barchart within the environment pycharm using python I would be very glad :)

Comment: `figursize` does not exist. Try `figsize`. Also, check out the matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html

Comment: Could you share what the data frame looks like? E.g. by using `df.head()`.

Comment: Please note that `alpha` is not a parameter for `sns.barplot()`. Documentation: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html